loading custom stack of PNG images. However, OHIF viewer web-image-loader is not working
I am trying to load custom stack of PNG images on my localhost OHIF viewport. I am following the tutorial by cornerstone. Also, I am following this github code which provides similar functionality and is supposed to be working.
I am running a localhost server that hosts the png images. I see the hosted localhost image on this live image website. However, the viewport is not getting the image data and I get “CornerstoneTools.stackPrefetch: No images in stack”, “Viewport is too small 0 0” errors when running this code in my localhost OHIF-viewer.
What could I be doing wrong? Any help is much appreciated.
